# Early 80s movie about a kind of superhero by accident, the guy breaks a car's wheels with his bare hands

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is a movie I was taken by the school teachers to watch with my peers in 2nd grade.

I just remember a few frames, the one in the title, the good guy breaking the a car's wheeldrive with his bare hands and also the same guy levitating when transformed into a superhero.

Weird movie, not for a kid who is 7 or 8. This was not an animated movie, just real actors (bad ones by the way). It got me thinking about static and materials resistance.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Were there musical numbers involved in it?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Are you thinking The Return of Captain Invincible ?

Comment: Indeed. However, I don't know if it has a case of breaking the car by lifting

Comment: @FuzzyBoots After watching the trailer, his primary power seems to be popping the buttons off of women's blouses.

Comment: He does have flight, it fits the timeframe, and it's definitely not appropriate for kids, but I could see someone thinking it was based on the colorful costumes, and bits like the pie fight.

Comment: Right timeframe, but TV not a movie; I was thinking Greatest American Hero: https://scifihorrorfantasy.files.wordpress.com/2016/05/greatest-american-hero-season-1-2-the-hit-car-ralph-super-hero-suit-lifts-car-william-katt.jpg?w=638